# Getting certain file types and check for a certain word within the results

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am trying to get all the .json files within a certain directory path, and to check if within each of the files found, if it contains a certain keyword.
In this case, the keyword I am looking for is called "case_control".

So while I perform a very simple scenario - creating a few json file, some embedded with the keyword, it seems to run and is fast. 
However as soon as I run the code in the actual directory path that I want test it onto, it is taking quite some time.. like 2+ hours and it is still 'running'

Is my code wrong or does it simply works slow in linux?

This is the command I am using:
`find /serverA/data -type f -name "*.json" | grep -rn "case_control" /serverA/data`

Answer (score 0):

try this find command.

this will list out the filenames ( if the pattern is matched in that file )

```
find /serverA/data -type f -name "*.json" | xargs grep -l "case_control"
```

Comment: Thanks, trying it out now.. While the result does not seems to be immediate, right now I am waiting again...

Comment: how many files you have ? if you have huge number of files, then it will take time.

Comment: about 1 to 2 hundreds? Actually your code is working.. I tried it with another keyword, and the result is almost immediate.. And I also just realize that because not all files contain the `case_control` keyword, I guess that is the cause of slowness..

Comment: yes, you are correct. But in your code, you are again running the grep command recursively against the directory. which is not correct